# how to multiply price and quantity in table using jquery append

Tags: php

I created a table that in html that has price and quantity, so i create jquery.
this is my code btw, my problem is how to insert code of  the total of quantity x price = total in jquery and html. this is RESULT of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hehe").click(function () {
        $(".xx").append("<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + $(".pName1").text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(".pPrice1").text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(".quan1").val() + "</td>" + "</tr>")

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div>
        <img id="lablabz" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random" alt="header" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="stableO">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p class="pName1"> ITEM NAME </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    ITEM PICTURE
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <p class="pPrice1"> 599.00PHP </td>
                <td><input class="quan1" type="textbox"> </input> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <button class="hehe"> Order</button> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table class="xx">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
                <P> CART </P>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Name of Product</td>
            <td>  Price </td>
            <td> Quantity </td>
            <td> Total </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

thanks in advance! hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hehe").click(function () {
       var price=parseFloat($(".pPrice1").text()).toFixed(2);
       var quantity=parseFloat($(".quan1").val()).toFixed(2);
       var total=parseFloat(price*quantity).toFixed(2);
        $(".xx").append("<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + $(".pName1").text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + price + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + quantity + "</td>"
                                 + "<td>" + total + "</td>" +
                                + "</tr>")

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div>
        <img id="lablabz" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random" alt="header" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="stableO">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p class="pName1"> ITEM NAME </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    ITEM PICTURE
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <p class="pPrice1"> 599.00PHP </td>
                <td><input class="quan1" type="textbox"> </input> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <button class="hehe"> Order</button> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table class="xx">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
                <P> CART </P>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Name of Product</td>
            <td>  Price </td>
            <td> Quantity </td>
            <td> Total </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Use parseFloat function to parse float value from input text.

Comment: @JavaScript101 welcome. I hope you will accept it as the answer.

Comment: how to add as the answer bro?

Comment: @JavaScript101  click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var pname = $(".pName1").text();
var pprice = $(".pPrice1").text();
var pquan = $('input > .quan1').val();

$("table > .xx").append('<tr><td>' + pname + '</td><td>' + pprice + '</td><td>' + pquan + '</td></tr>');
```

EDIT: Misread the question. The only thing that needs to be added in my code is the new variable that counts the result price. But this way is easier, because you can just declare a new variable and do your Math there.

---

Analysis

```
var pname = $(".pName1").text();
var pprice = $(".pPrice1").text();
var pquan = $('input > .quan1').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hehe").click(function(){
  $(".xx").append( "<tr>" + "<td>"+$(".pName1").text() +"</td>" + "<td>"+$(".pPrice1").text() + "</td>" + "<td>"+$(".quan1").val() + "</td>"+"</tr>" + '<td>' + pname + '</td><td>' + pprice + '</td><td>' + pquan + '</td></tr>');
 });
});
```

As said. This code will not show any total. It should only give you the same values in a new `<tr>`.
**Also** best practice is to declare your variable inside your function. Below is a clean up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".hehe").click(function(){

 var pname = $(".pName1").text();
 var pprice = $(".pPrice1").text();
 var pquan = $('input > .quan1').val();
 var ptotal = pprice * pquan;

 $("table > .xx").append('<tr><td>' + pname + '</td><td>' + pprice + '</td><td>' + pquan +  '</td><td>' + ptotal + '</td></tr>');
 });
});
```

Comment: the total is undefined bro, 

var pname = $(".pName1").text();
  var pprice = $(".pPrice1").text();
  var pquan = $('input > .quan1').val();
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hehe").click(function(){
   $(".xx").append( "<tr>" +
         "<td>"+$(".pName1").text() +"</td>" +
         "<td>"+$(".pPrice1").text() + "</td>" +
         "<td>"+$(".quan1").val() + "</td>"+"</tr>" +
        '<td>' + pname + '</td><td>' + pprice + '</td><td>' + pquan + '</td></tr>');
         
        
  });
  });